# Sencha architect grid panel alias

Tags: javascript, extjs

I can not find the alias parameter in sencha architect of my grid panel to use it in my controller.

Someone you have an idea?

thank you

Comment: What do you mean you cannot find the alias parameter? Can you provide some code? Or at least elaborate some more...

Comment: @cclerville : i use sencha architect with extjs 4.0.7 and in the case of the property target there is : "CSS LIKE SELECTOR" and in the documentation they write only id and itemid... the example of the code is with extjs 4.1